# chart_Series with stock history from yahoofinancer

Tags: r, quantmod

I am getting an error when I try to make a plot with `chart_Series()` that works with `chartSeries()`.

I get the data with `getSymbols()` and can then use `chartSeries()` to get stock chart:

```r
library(quantmod)
AAPL <- getSymbols("AAPL", from=Sys.Date()-84, auto.assign=F)
chartSeries(AAPL,theme="white",major.ticks="months",minor.ticks = F)
```

[image]

However if I use `chart_Series()`:

```r
chart_Series(AAPL,theme="white",major.ticks="months",minor.ticks=F)
```

I have the error "Error in theme$col : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors"

I want to use `chart_Series()` because it supports the `par()` function.

How to resolve the error in `chart_Series()`? Thank you for reading my posts :)

Comment: hmmm what is `Ticker`? and `data`? and `ticker`?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I edited out data and ticker. The yahoofinancer package uses "Ticker" class. https://yahoofinancer.rsquaredacademy.com/

Answer (score 0):

`chart_Series()` does not have the same arguments as `chartSeries()`, so they're not meant to be drop-in replacements of each other. `chart_Series()` uses a white background by default, so you don't need to change `theme` if that is all you want.

```r
library(quantmod)
aapl <- getSymbols("AAPL", periodicity = "1min", auto.assign = FALSE)
chart_Series(aapl)
```

[image]

Comment: The question is to use chart_Series with yahoofinancer package. 
yahoofinancer has intraday yahoo data. 
chart_Series can use par to plot multiple charts in a plot.

Comment: Your question doesn't use intraday data though. And quantmod supports intraday yahoo data in versions >= 0.4.25

Comment: Do try yahoofinancer. It has about 10min delayed intraday data. For example today is 5 Sep and market is not closed yet, the price history data for AAPL will include 5 Sep

Comment: yahoofinancer uses the same endpoint as quantmod. `getSymbols()` uses `to = Sys.Date()` by default. Set `to = Sys.Date()+1` if you want today's data too.

Comment: Thanks bro, this is what I required. Wish I had know earlier!